# dropping rows where date aligns with max value of another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` named `au` from which I want to drop the rows where `date` aligns with observations where `bal==bal.max()`. For example, if `bal==bal.max()` is associated with `2009-08-01`, then I want to drop all other observations for which `date=='2009-08-01'`. Below is what I've tried but both attempts result in `ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare`

```
au = au[au.date != au.date[au.bal==au.bal.max()]]
au = au[au.date != au.date[au.bal==au.bal.max()].values]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `idxmax` and @jezrael's setup

***setup***

```
au = pd.DataFrame({'bal':[1,2,3,4],
                   'date':['2009-08-01','2009-08-01','2009-08-02', '2009-08-02'],
                   'C':[7,8,9,1]})
```

***solution***

```
dmax = au.date.loc[au.bal.idxmax()]
au[au.date != dmax]

   C  bal        date
0  7    1  2009-08-01
1  8    2  2009-08-01
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need get scalar from one item `Series` by [`item`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.item.html) or `values` with selected firts value by [0]:

```
au = pd.DataFrame({'bal':[1,2,3,4],
                   'date':['2009-08-01','2009-08-01','2009-08-02', '2009-08-02'],
                   'C':[7,8,9,1]})

print (au)
   C  bal        date
0  7    1  2009-08-01
1  8    2  2009-08-01
2  9    3  2009-08-02
3  1    4  2009-08-02


print (au[au.date != au.loc[au.bal==au.bal.max(), 'date'].item()])
   C  bal        date
0  7    1  2009-08-01
1  8    2  2009-08-01
```

Solution with [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) - create `Series` with `date` first:

```
print (au.set_index('date').bal.idxmax())
2009-08-02

au = au[au.date != au.set_index('date').bal.idxmax()]
print (au)
   C  bal        date
0  7    1  2009-08-01
1  8    2  2009-08-01
```